# how to get macbuntu desktop environment

Tags: macbuntu

Recently i saw a post on ask Ubuntu regarding mac-buntu and i got curious about it and tried installing mac-buntu through this command in terminal `sudo apt-get install macbuntu-desktop` , but the result was shown saying no such package or directory

Is there any other way to install mac-buntu without actually creating a partition in your hard disk?

if yes then please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's 2 version you can find the old one on 'https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/macbuntu/'

#### Installation :

```
$ wget https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/macbuntu/macbuntu-10.10/v2.3/Macbuntu-10.10.tar.gz -O /tmp/Macbuntu-10.10.tar.gz
$ tar xzvf /tmp/Macbuntu-10.10.tar.gz -C /tmp
$ cd /tmp/Macbuntu-10.10/
$ gksu './install.sh' && sudo apt-get update && sudo shutdown -r
```

Comment: you mean first i have to download the file and then install via these commands in termnal

Comment: wget command is gonna download it

Comment: can i use it along with my preinstalled gnome desktop

Comment: maybe but i don't know how

Comment: if you already installed the gnome desktop you can change the environment in the lightdm 'login form' like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/tlRhA.png